# Задача на линейно разделимую выборку на python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

В первой строке дано 2 числа через пробел: n-объем выборки, а m-размерность пространства.Далее n строк содержат значения x и y. Нужно найти вектор гиперплоскости. Для решения использовать только numpy. Ответ - строка с координатами вектора через пробел. Не могу найти ошибку, на части тестов выдает неверное решение.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
input_s=sys.stdin.readlines()
#print(input_s)
n=int(input_s[0][0])
#print(n)
m=int(input_s[0][2])
#print(m)
file_obj=open("data_problem2.txt","w")
for i in range(n):
  file_obj.write(input_s[i+1])
file_obj.close()
data=np.loadtxt("data_problem2.txt",delimiter=" ")
x=data[:, :m]
y=data[:,m]
x=np.hstack((x,np.ones((n,1))))

w=np.zeros((1,m+1))
for i in range(n):
  if (np.dot(w.T,x[i]))*y[i]<=0:
    w=w+x[i]*y[i] 
#w=w/((np.dot(w.T,w))**0.5)
solve=str("")
for i in range(m):
  solve=solve+str(w[i])+" "
print(solve)
```

Comment: А входные данные и ответы конкретных тестов у вас есть?

Comment: Нет, задача принимается сервером (нужно решить для курсов)